# React Passing Component Function - cannot use in function

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am attempting to pass a function down to a child component in a react router. I've figured out how to use render to send my props through and am using withRouter to make them available to my current state.

I cannot get the function to pass through to another function defined by the component receiving it.

Sample code below - kinda chopped up

```
// generic class with a router attempting to pass a function to a child
class App extends Component{
...
modalLogin = () => {
    console.log('modal login called')
    this.setState({modalLoginTrigger:true})
}

render(){
   render(
   <router> 
      <switch> 
         <Router ....more paths>  
         <Route path='/product/:_id' render={(props) =>(<ProductPage onModalLogin={this.modalLogin} />)}/>
      </siwtch>
   </router>)
```

ProductPage - receiving all of the parent props correctly, but not connecting the addToBinder() function to this.props.onModalLogin

```
class ProductPage extends Component {
    addToBinder(){
        this.props.onModalLogin()
    }

    render() {
       <div>
           <a className="cb_binder-link__add-remove col-xs-6" onClick={this.addToBinder} href="#">
       </div>
}
export default withRouter(ProductPage) ;
```

When my onclick function in my anchor is called, I am getting a

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
>   This is coming from addToBinder()

When I call the onModalLogin function from the render itself, it works.

```
class ProductPage extends Component {
    addToBinder(){
        this.props.onModalLogin()
    }

    render() {
       <div>
           <a className="cb_binder-link__add-remove col-xs-6" onClick={this.props.onModalLogin} href="#">
       </div>
}
export default withRouter(ProductPage) ;
```

I want to be able to conduct business logic in addToBinder before calling onModalLogin - e.g. check if the user is logged in, prompt for a login if not. How do i get this to connect?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to bind this to your addToBinder function, so try:
onClick={() => this.addToBinder()} or onClick={this.addToBinder.bind(this)}

Or actually, look at how you defined modalLogin, just do the same thing for addToBinder, that autobinds this to the function so you don't have to do either of the above methods. That is why it works when you just pass this.modalLogin to onClick.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, I needed to bind my onClick to This

```
class ProductPage extends Component {
   addToBinder(){
      this.props.onModalLogin()
   }   

   render() {
       <div>
           <a  onClick={this.props.onModalLogin.bind(this)} href="#">
       </div>
   }
}
```

Following up on the other answer provided by Dal, redefining the addToBinder function, passed the scope up to the parent.

```
addToBinder = () => {
    this.props.onModalLogin()
}
```

This works cleanly as well.